# ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined with JEST

Tags: next.js, jestjs

I have to test `next.js` app with `jest` using version 29.

When I try to test some components, I have this error:

`ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined`

Note that setImmediate is not used explicitly by the developers in any component, and I use `jsdom` environment for testing.

Any help or clarification please